# UITableView pull-to-add interaction pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a pull-to-add interaction to a UITableView, like the app Clear does but without the fancy UI effects - just trying to plain simply add a new cell to the table view after it has been dragged down at least half the height of a new cell.

All works but the problem is that the UIScrollView makes it always bounce back to its contentOffset (-64 with UINavigationController title bar) after releasing the drag, even after the new cell is added.

How do I avoid / prevent this? I tried setContentOffset to 0, -64 with no animation but it seems to be ignored, still bounces back.

Any advice is welcome!

[image: Unwanted bounce-back effect]

The placeHolderCell is a UITableViewCell added as subview to self (UITableViewController)

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let delta = abs(Double(scrollView.contentOffset.y)) - abs(Double(initialScrollViewContentOffset))

    if delta >= Double(placeHolderCell.frame.height / 2) {
        insertNewObject(scrollView)
    }

    placeHolderCell.removeFromSuperview()

}

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

    objects.insert(NSDate(), atIndex: 0)

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.beginUpdates()

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

    tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced something similar, try to uncheck (adjust view insets) for the desired view controller nib or storyboard view controller, otherwise paste a screenshot or explain more.

Comment: See this GIF for better understanding: [GIF link](http://giphy.com/gifs/xT0BKlVnuzFVBtbpVS)

Answer (score 0):

Try tableView.reloadData()
Instead of tableView.beginUpdates() tableView.endUpdates()

This should work, but it may not look very smooth afterwards.

I'm not sure what would happen, but you could try this then:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1){
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help sadly